# How to read a portion of an image using RMagick?

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm trying to load a large image and crop it into tiles really fast and with low memory consumption. An example is the way gdal2tiles script http://www.maptiler.org/ does it, but gdal2tiles doesn't output the tiles the way I want them to be. Therefore I decided to develop my own version using ruby and RMagick(Imagemagick).(gdal2tiles barely uses any memory).

What I notice when using RMgick is that I need to load the whole image to memory first which kinda kills my system. Is there a way to read a portion of a image file manipulate it and then read the rest ?? Or maybe I should do it in some other way or use other libraries.

Comment: I've found the stream option http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#stream Any idea of how to use it through RMagick?

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is call descructive methods only. Don't call `img.crop` but `img.crop!`, that will save some memory.

But you might be interested in one of the alternatives. The problem with memory you describe, is almost unavoidable with RMagick. There are quite a lot of [alternatives](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/image_processing.html) for RMagick for this very reason.

Because you need simple tasks only, I think the following libraries are usefull for you, because they are extremely optimised, but their featureset is limited.

- [MiniMagick](https://github.com/probablycorey/mini_magick)
- [Chunky PNG](https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png)
- [Oily PNG](https://github.com/wvanbergen/oily_png)